# How insert pagination with limit posts?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I want return ALL posts in the table Mysql and each page show only 6 posts and in bottom show pagination.

I can return all posts, but I dont know how work with pagination:

```
    <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM myTable";       

        $variable = $crud->viewdatas($query);
        foreach ($variable as $key => $value) { 

     ?>
  <div class="col-md-1"> 
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="/category/<?php echo $value['post_slug'] ?>" >
        <img src="http://example.com/uploads/images/<?php echo $value['post_slug'] ?>.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php 
        }
 ?>
```

I created Friendly urls with post_slug column in mysql and in htacess

```
RewriteRule ^category/?$ example.com/my_category.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^category\/(.*)\/?$ example.com/posts.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
```

Pagination:

```
<nav style="text-align:center">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li>
      <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

When click a number in the pagination link, direct url:

```
site.com/category/1
site.com/category/2
site.com/category/3
...
```

But I dont know how start for insert php pagination.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Are you using some sort of incrementing row in your table?
If so, you could do something like this

URL would be 
site.com/category/yourpage.php?page=2

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
$resultsLimit = 6;
$upperLimit = 6 * $page;
$lowerLimit = (6*page) - $resultsLimit;
$query = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id <= {$upperLimit} AND id >= {$lowerLimit}";
```

Adapt to your project of course;

Comment: Thank you @Addil, but I dont understand how insert link in each link: previous, 1,2,3,..., next?